# Laravel query problem in join table and group by

Tags: php, laravel, join, group-by, laravel-query-builder

I have a query problem in my join table and group by. This is not working. What am I missing? It works with MySQL queries on XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1055 'm-shop-api.users.email' isn't in GROUP BY
> (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`phone`,
> `users`.`address`, COUNT(*) AS total from `orders` inner join `users`
> on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` where `apt_rjt_order` = 1 group
> by `users`.`id`)

```
$query = Order::query();
$query->where('apt_rjt_order', 1)
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.phone', 
        'users.address', 'orders.created_at');

return $query->groupBy('users.id')->get();
```

Comment: You've got an aggregate function in there, `COUNT(*)` with an incomplete group by. Laravel must be enabling 'strict group by' or whatever its called. Try removing the "total" column from your model or add the other fields to your groupBy.

Comment: What @mpen above is correct, another solution is in your `mysql.ini` disable/remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.